# imap_open authentication failure on localhost

Tags: php, gmail-imap, php-7.4

I'm using `PHP 7.4.15` and `Gmail IMAP` to fetch emails from server.
Same credentials work on QA env but failing on my local machine, I'm using the following code:

```
$username = 'testing+some_email_queue@example.com';
$password = '<some password>';

$imap = imap_open('{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', $username, $password);

var_dump($imap);
```

I'm running my code example using the following command: `php -f imap.php` and output is:

```
PHP Warning:  imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in C:\Projects\<path>\imap.php on line 9

Warning: imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX in C:\Projects\<path>\imap.php on line 9
bool(false)
PHP Notice:  Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: [AUTHENTICATIONFAILED] Invalid credentials (Failure) (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Too many login failures (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0

Notice: Unknown: Too many login failures (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

In my `php.ini` file `imap` extension is enabled.

Any idea what might be the reason?

Comment: `Invalid credentials` seems like a pretty clear error message to me. I will wager that they are not, in fact, the same. Also, please don't use `novalidate-cert` for live servers -- if that cert goes bad, you want the login to fail.

Comment: @AlexHowansky yes, but same credentials work on QA, I simply copy pasted them

Comment: Gmail actually blocks logins via IMAP unless you add this request as a valid app and use those app credentials.  You can enable less secure apps on your gmail option but this is highly discouraged and should only be used to cross check connection and code accuracy.

Comment: @nice_dev I just checked and Less secure apps are enabled already

Comment: @Arkadi Are you able to login with this credentials?